# Parsing special node tags with Nokogiri

Tags: xml, nokogiri

List item

I am trying to parse this node and try to remove it using the following code:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('Web.config'))
@doc.search('system.serviceModel').each do |node|
  puts node
end

<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="" 
            </service>
               </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Doesn't seem to work using this special tag with a dot in the middle. It works with other types of plain nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `@doc.search` to  `@doc.xpath` should work for you. Nokogiri is interpreting `system.serviceModel` as CSS, i.e. as a system tag with a serviceModel class. By switching to the xpath method, Nokogiri will not try to interpret the search as CSS.